# Linking two lists together in C

Tags: c, list, graph

I am fairly new to C programming and I'm trying to have a graph made of a list of nodes and a a list of bridges which should point to another node of the first list.
To be clear:

> **node1 -> bridge -> node2 and in the list of nodes node1->node2->nodeN.**
>   inputs  
>   nodeA  
>   nodeB  
>   nodeC  
>   nodeD  
>   and second input 
>   nodeA nodeB  
>   nodeA nodeD  
>   nodeB nodeC  
>   nodeC nodeD

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXL 20


struct node{
    char name[MAXL];
    struct node *next;
    struct link *bridge;
};
struct link{
    struct link *next;
    struct node *bridge;
};

struct node *insertnode(struct node *node, char name[MAXL]);
struct node *bridgelink(struct node *node, struct node *link, char finishname[MAXL]);
struct link *insert(struct node *node, struct link *link, char startname[MAXL], char finishname[MAXL]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char t_name[MAXL], start[MAXL], finish[MAXL];
    struct node *mynode=NULL;
    FILE *innodes;
    FILE *inlinks;
    innodes=fopen("innodes.txt", "r");
    inlinks=fopen("inlinks.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(innodes, "%s", t_name)!=EOF){
        mynode=insertnode(mynode, t_name);
    }

    while (fscanf(inlinks, "%s %s", start, finish)!=EOF) {
        while(mynode!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(mynode->name, start)==0){
            mynode->bridge=insert(mynode, mynode->bridge, start, finish);

        }
        mynode=mynode->next;
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
struct node *insertnode(struct node *node, char name[MAXL]){
    struct node *newptr=NULL;

    newptr=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(newptr->name, name);
    newptr->next=node;
    return newptr;
 }

struct node *bridgelink(struct node *node, struct node *link, char finishname[MAXL]){
    struct node *newptr=NULL;
    newptr=malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newptr->next=node;

    return newptr;


}
struct link *insert(struct node *node, struct link *link, char startname[MAXL], char finishname[MAXL]){
    struct link *newptr;
    newptr=malloc(sizeof(struct link));
    while(node!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(node->name, finishname)==0){
            newptr->bridge=bridgelink(newptr->bridge, node, finishname);

        }
        node=node->next;
    }

    newptr->next=link;
    return newptr;

}
```

Comment: What problems are you having? I'm still not very clear: your list of nodes is just a list of nodes, and not a representation of the graph, but then you have separate 'bridge' structures which do represent edges of the graph? How many bridges can originate at a given node - any number, or 0-1, or exactly 1? Are bridges directed or do they need to be stored bidirectionally?

Comment: Can you please provide a) Sample input (minimal example which still triggers the unwanted behaviour), b) Expected output, c) Actual output.

Comment: The `bridgelink()` function doesn't use the `link` or `finishname` parameters. Also, `bridgelink()` creates a new `node` just like `insertnode()` but it fails to initalize the `name` field. How is `bridgelink()` intended to differ from `insertnode()`?

Comment: What is a "bridge" in context of graphs? Do you mean "edges"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs some error-checking code, but appears to do what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXL 20


struct node{
    char name[MAXL];
    struct node *next;
    struct link *bridge;
};
struct link{
    struct link *next;
    struct node *bridge;
};

struct node *insertnode(struct node *node, char name[MAXL]);
static void bridge(struct node *snode, struct node *fnode);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char t_name[MAXL], start[MAXL], finish[MAXL];
    struct node *mynode=NULL;
    struct node *snode, *fnode, *tnode;
    struct link *tlink;
    FILE *innodes;
    FILE *inlinks;
    innodes=fopen("innodes.txt", "r");
    inlinks=fopen("inlinks.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(innodes, "%s", t_name)!=EOF){
        mynode=insertnode(mynode, t_name);
    }

    while (fscanf(inlinks, "%s %s", start, finish)==2) {
        snode=NULL;
        fnode=NULL;
        tnode=mynode;
        while(tnode!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(tnode->name, start)==0){
                snode=tnode;
                if(fnode!=NULL){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(strcmp(tnode->name, finish)==0){
                fnode=tnode;
                if(snode!=NULL){
                    break;
                }
            }
            tnode=tnode->next;
        }
        if(snode!=NULL && fnode!=NULL){
            bridge(snode, fnode);
        }else{
            if(snode==NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "start node '%s' not valid\n", start);
            }
            if(fnode==NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "finish node '%s' not valid\n", finish);
            }
        }
    }

    for(snode=mynode; snode!=NULL; snode=snode->next){
        if(snode->bridge==NULL){
            printf("%s\n", snode->name);
        }else{
            for(tlink=snode->bridge; tlink!=NULL; tlink=tlink->next){
                printf("%s => %s\n", snode->name, tlink->bridge->name);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

struct node *insertnode(struct node *node, char name[MAXL]){
    struct node *newptr=NULL;

    newptr=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(newptr->name, name);
    newptr->next=node;
    newptr->bridge=NULL;
    return newptr;
}

static void bridge(struct node *snode, struct node *fnode){
    struct link *newptr=NULL;

    newptr=malloc(sizeof(struct link));
    newptr->bridge=fnode;
    newptr->next=snode->bridge;
    snode->bridge=newptr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ian